# Having two parameters within a CASE statement within a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query to produce all of the records where various parameters apply.

Say the table concerned holds details about people.

I want to produce the records for both 'Male' and 'Female' entries but I only want to show the men with an age lower than say, '40'.

Currently I have a query like this;

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE gender IN('Male', 'Female') AND age < 40
```

How do I apply the age rule to the men only? With a CASE statement?

**EDIT**

As I have many other parameters within the WHERE clause which I didn't mention here, I want to avoid the use of the OR operator, apologies for not stating this to start with.

Comment: You can't take one of the answers, and just wrap the gender/age caluse in another set of parentheses?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, where would I place the parentheses and how would this solve the OR problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no need for a `CASE` statement just alter your `WHERE` clause to include one filter specific for `'Male'` records and one line for `'Female'` records:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (gender = 'Male' AND age < 40)
    OR gender = 'Female'
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b918/1)

Edit if you have more items in your `WHERE` clause, you would just use parentheses to add more criterion:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
(
    (gender = 'Male' AND age < 40)
        OR gender = 'Female'
)
AND -- place your other WHERE filters here
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to write this, but this is probably the clearest:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE gender = 'Female' 
    or (gender = 'Male' AND age < 40)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (gender = 'Female' OR (gender = 'Male' AND age < 40)) AND ...
    -- the rest of your WHERE criteria goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (age < 40 and gender = 'Male')
or gender = 'Female'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IN no =

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE gender IN('Female') OR (gender IN('Male') AND age < 40);
```